# ObjectQuery as a parameter in ESQL

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-sql, objectquery

Assume I have 2 entities: `Ent` and `SubEnt` with N:1 relationship. So, there are navigation properties `SubEnt.Ents` and `Ent.SubEnt`. Also, I have some ObjectQuery defined:

```
ObjectQuery<SubEnt> se;
```

How can I create ESQL query that selects all entities from `Ent` that have `Ent.SubEnt` from `se`?
Something like that:

```
SELECT VALUE it FROM Ent WHERE Ent.SubEnt IN @p
```

Where @p == se.
It looks like a nested query. But this syntax is not correct because "Only scalar types are supported".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have ObjectQuery you cannot pass it back to ESQL. So you must either write the whole query in ESQL without separates `se` or you must work on with ObjectQuery itself. In later case try something like:

```
var query = from e in context.Ents
            join s in se on e.Ent.Id equals s.Id
            select e;
```

Unless you example is just some simplification of bigger query you can also simply try:

```
var query = se.SelectMany(s => s.Ents).Distinct();
```